# Upload file (byte array) to SharePoint library using Java

Tags: file-upload, java

Apologies in advance for such a long read but I had to provide as much details as possible.

I have a web application (WA) running on a JAVA middleware. User uploads a file via the WA which is then sent as a `FormData` binary to the middleware via REST.

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryB7ko1mMLg3nV8YZE
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename="Hello.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain
```

Next up, in the middleware I construct a `javax.ws.rs.client.Client` like so:

```
ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig(); 
ApacheConnectorProvider provider = new ApacheConnectorProvider();
config.connectorProvider(provider);
javax.ws.rs.client.Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(config).register(MultiPartFeature.class);
client.register(new BearerAuthenticationRequestFilter(token); // Bearer token
config.register(new ClientRequestFilter() {
    @Override
    public void filter(ClientRequestContext requestCtxt) throws IOException {
        requestCtxt.getHeaders().add("Accept", "application/json; odata=verbose");
        requestCtxt.getHeaders().putSingle("Content-Type", "application/json; odata=verbose");
        requestCtxt.getHeaders().add("X-RequestDigest", formDigestToken); // FormDigestValue
    }
});
```

My query parameters are like so:

```
String @a1 = ... //encoded path to the SharePoint library
String @a2 = URLEncoder.encode("'" + fileName + "'", StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()).replace("\\+", "%20");
```

The `target`:

```
String sharepointRestUrl = // https://abc.sharepoint.com/sites/dms/Shared documents/...

javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget target = client.target(sharepointRestUrl)
        .path("/GetFolderByServerRelativePath(DecodedUrl=@a1)/Files/AddUsingPath(DecodedUrl=@a2,AutoCheckoutOnInvalidData=@a3)")
        .queryParam("@a1", a1)
        .queryParam("@a2", a2)
        .queryParam("@a3", true);
```

And finally the POST request like so:

```
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileByteArray);

MediaType contentType = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE;

javax.ws.rs.client.Invocation.Builder request = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);

javax.ws.rs.core.Response response = request.post(Entity.entity(in, contentType));
```

I do see parsing of the file in the logs:

```
{
  "buf" : "SGFsbG8gdGVzdCAxMjM=",
  "pos" : 0,
  "mark" : 0,
  "count" : 14
}
```

The file, however, doesn't get uploaded. The error I receive back is:

```
{"odata.error":{"code":"-1, System.IO.IOException","message":{... "value":"I/O error occurred."}}}
```

If instead of building the `Entity` with `InputStream` I try to use `MultiPart` like so:

```
MultiPart multipart = new MultiPart(); // OR FormDataMultiPart multipart = new FormDataMultiPart();

FormDataBodyPart xRequestDigestPart = new FormDataBodyPart("X-RequestDigest", formDigestToken);
multipart.bodyPart(xRequestDigestPart);

InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileByteArray);

StreamDataBodyPart filePart = new StreamDataBodyPart("attachment", in, fileName);

multipart.bodyPart(filePart);

MediaType contentType = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE;
contentType = Boundary.addBoundary(contentType);

javax.ws.rs.client.Invocation.Builder request = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
    
javax.ws.rs.core.Response response = request.post(Entity.entity(multipart, contentType));
```

the file still doesn't uploaded but I see an additional error in the log:

```
Cannot get entity on a MultiPart instance (through reference chain: org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPart["entity"])
[EXCEPTION]
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Cannot get entity on a MultiPart instance (through reference chain: org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPart["entity"])
```

Where is it possibly going wrong? I have been struggling with this for a week now. It seems like I have also used up all the help available on the internet.

P.S. Upload does work via Postman client so it's probably not related to access/authorisation. I have a feeling it has something to do with the way I am constructing the request body.

I would greatly appreciate if someone could help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered a library with some examples?
https://gitlab.com/quantr/sharepoint/Sharepoint-Java-API